# How to filter text using start and end string or character

Tags: powershell

Can anyone assist me in filtering the banner message and extract only the text "13:12:03.539 UTC Sun Mar 6 2015" as output?

```
C
-=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=-
S Y S T E M   A C C E S S   W A R N I N G
-=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=-
You have connected to a private network.  This system is to only be used
by authorized personnel for authorized business purposes.  All activity
is monitored and logged.  Unauthorized access or activity is a violation
of law.
If you have connected to this system by mistake, disconnect now.

13:12:03.539 UTC Sun Mar 6 2015
C
-=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=-
S Y S T E M   A C C E S S   W A R N I N G
-=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=-
You have connected to a private network.  This system is to only be used
by authorized personnel for authorized business purposes.  All activity
is monitored and logged.  Unauthorized access or activity is a violation
of law.
If you have connected to this system by mistake, disconnect now.

    Line       User       Host(s)              Idle       Location
*514 vty 0     vijay.dada idle                 00:00:01 X.X.X.X
  Interface    User               Mode         Idle     Peer Address
C
-=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=-
   S Y S T E M   A C C E S S   W A R N I N G
-=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=-
You have connected to a private network.  This system is to only be used
by authorized personnel for authorized business purposes.  All activity
is monitored and logged.  Unauthorized access or activity is a violation
of law.
If you have connected to this system by mistake, disconnect now.
```

I tried using the below code unable to make it work.Request to assist.

```
$arr = @()
$path = "yourFilePath"
$pattern = "(?<=.*C
-)\w+?(?=disconnect now.*)"

Get-Content $path | Foreach {
    if ([Regex]::IsMatch($_, $pattern)) {
        $arr += [Regex]::Match($_, $pattern)
    }
}
$arr | Foreach {$_.Value}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply grep the line you're looking for:

```
$path    = 'C:\path\to\your.txt'
$pattern = '^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3} .* \w{3} \d{1,2} \d{4}$'

(Get-Content $path) -match $pattern
```

For removing what you don't want instead of selecting what you want you need to convert the text to a single string (by default `Get-Content` produces an array of strings and multiline matches don't work with that kind of input) and then replace the banner in that string, e.g. like this:

```
$path   = 'C:\path\to\your.txt'
$banner = @'
C
-=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=-
S Y S T E M   A C C E S S   W A R N I N G
-=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=- -=*=-
You have connected to a private network.  This system is to only be used
by authorized personnel for authorized business purposes.  All activity
is monitored and logged.  Unauthorized access or activity is a violation
of law.
If you have connected to this system by mistake, disconnect now.
'@ -replace "`r?`n", "`r`n"

((Get-Content $path | Out-String) -replace [regex]::Escape($banner)).Trim()
```

The trailing replacement in the banner definition is to ensure that the banner string has line breaks encoded as CR-LF, regardless of whether you run the code from a script or by copy/pasting it in a PowerShell console.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic :).Short and Sweet.Thanks a lot.It worked.

Comment: But can it be more generalised where in its considers the banner as pattern.Becoz i have been running different commands and everytime the output is different but banner is same.

Comment: @Angsar, Your answer just worked fine for the previous output.But its does not work with current updated output.As said i will be running multiple different commands where in the output precedes and succeeds with the mentioned banner and want to filter those.Any solutions is very much helpful and appreciated.

Comment: @Vijay Contrary to what you claimed the third banner in your sample output is different from the other two banners (the "system access warning" line is indented).

Comment: @Angsar, You are Simply Superb :).Minute details can create such a frustration.Very much satisfied for  your utmost patience,brilliance and Confidence.Thank you very much.